# How to display pdf inside container of widget [flutter-web]

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-web

I would like to open pdf file in my flutter-web project, as long as I know... when I open the pdf, it always navigates me to new tab, is there a way to display pdf inside container of widget flutter?
So, far I only open the pdf file by doing this

```
html.window.open('http://xxxx.pdf',"my_pdf");
```

I still didn't know how to put it inside widget flutter

Comment: Please provide your question with some code that you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In the demo code, I add `blue border` on `Container`
code snippet

```
class Iframe extends StatelessWidget {
  Iframe() {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('iframe', (int viewId) {
      var iframe = html.IFrameElement();
      iframe.src = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';
      return iframe;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'iframe'));
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'dart:io' if (dart.library.html) 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Iframe()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Iframe extends StatelessWidget {
  Iframe() {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('iframe', (int viewId) {
      var iframe = html.IFrameElement();
      iframe.src = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';
      return iframe;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'iframe'));
  }
}
```